# Get the posts with more likes in the same lebel, in one table self referencing with doctrine and symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to show all the replys to one post in symfony, but the replys need to be ordered by the amount of likes, that are saved in other table. The relation with the parent and the children are in the same table, and i don't know i are any form to get all the elements ordered in one query.

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. It will help us helping you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but finally i added an oorderBy in the post definition entitiy in doctrine, and later regenerate the likes fields, and finally i ordered by the amount of likes :)